# Как отобразить данные из БД Firebase в Android приложении в виде таблицы с несколькими колонками?

Tags: java, android

подскажите пожалуйста, с помощью какого элемента в android можно отобразить данные из бд Firebase в виде таблицы, чтобы данные отображались в строчку и как заполнить эту таблицу?

Comment: `android-studio` - метка связанная с вопросами по поводу самой ide но никак не с данным вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо таблицу просто для данных то полистайте это : http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/tablelayout.php